# Assisting Solve to generate solution to a complicated equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, physics, assumptions

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
$Assumptions = {r ∈ Reals, r >= 0, rh ∈ Reals, 
   rh > 0, Q ∈ Reals, 
   Q >= 0, α ∈ Reals, α >= 0, 
   P ∈ Reals, P >= 0, L ∈ Reals, L > 0, 
   l ∈ Reals, l >= 0};
S[rh_, α_] = 
  3 α π^2 rh + 1/2 π^2 rh^3 // Simplify;
V[rh_] = (π^2 rh^4)/2 // Simplify;
ϕ[rh_, Q_] = (π Q)/(16 rh^2) // Simplify;
M[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] = 
  1/8 π (3 α + 3 rh^2 + 4 P π rh^4) + (
    8 rh^2 (ϕ[rh, Q])^2)/π // Simplify;
T[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] = (
   rh (π^2 (3 + 8 P π rh^2) - 64 (ϕ[rh, Q])^2))/(
   6 π^3 (2 α + rh^2)) // Simplify;
G[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] = 
  M[rh, Q, α, 
     P] - (T[rh, Q, α, P] S[rh, α]) - (ϕ[rh, 
       Q] Q) // Simplify;
f[r_, rh_, Q_, α_, P_] = 
  1 + r^2/(
     2 α) (1 - Sqrt[
       1 + (32 α M[rh, Q, α, P])/(
        3 π r^4) - (α Q^2)/(3 r^6) - (16 π α P)/
        3]) // Simplify;
Veff[r_] = f[r, rh, Q, α, P] (L^2/r^2 + 1) // FullSimplify;
eqn = L^2 == (r0^3* 
       D[f[r0, rh, Q, α, P], 
        r0])/(2 f[r0, rh, Q, α, P] - 
       r0 D[f[r0, rh, Q, α, P], r0]) // FullSimplify;

sol = Block[{α = 0.01, Q = 0.5, L = 20, P = 0.08}, 
  Solve[eqn, r0, Reals]]
```

In this case, the `Solve` function returns the result but suppose I want to get my results in terms of P as well, so if I change the above code to

```
 sol = Block[{α = 0.01, Q = 0.5, L = 20}, Solve[eqn, r0, Reals]]
```

I observe that it doesn't generate a solution and keeps on running forever. How to resolve this issue by assisting `Solve`?

Comment: First thing I would try is getting rid of that big denominator and that makes it look like you could combine those two big ugly identical square roots into one big ugly square root. That might make it easier for Solve and doesn't look like it should be too hard for you to do this.

Comment: `eqn=200.*r0^4*(-8+r0^4)*rh^2*Sqrt[9-0.0075/r0^6+(0.0036+0.0075/rh^2+0.36*rh^2)/r0^4+P*(-1.5079644737231006+(1.5079644737231006*rh^4)/r0^4)]==300.*rh^2+(600.-100.5309649148734*P)*r0^8*rh^2+r0^2*(-200.-95.75*rh^2-9600.*rh^4-40212.385965949354*P*rh^6)` is less than half the size of the original and should be easier for `Solve` or `Reduce`. You just need to confirm that denominator that I multiplied both sides by cannot be zero. You might multiply by a power of `r0` to get all those out of the denominators if you can show that `r0!=0` and that should help even more. Check all this CAREFULLY

Comment: @Bill thank you for the suggestion. So basically, it's the square root which is the issue? I understand your point and have checked the calculations. There is still a square root after simplification, maybe that's why `Solve` is unable to provide any solution.

Comment: I can't be certain what the issue is. But often denominators make things harder and big complicated repeated blocks that can be safely turned into one block sometimes helps. BUT you said it worked quickly when P had a value and doesn't without that. I'd look at how that changes the problem. Sometimes replacing a variable with a constant can make a problem MUCH easier, but I haven't figured out exactly what that does here. I've fiddled with your expression and get a 16th power polynomial in r0! Yikes. But I don't have a quick complete solution for you. Please check all this CAREFULLY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, `Solve` can provide a solution with `Q` as the unknown variable instead of `P`:

```
$Assumptions = {r ∈ Reals, r >= 0, rh ∈ Reals, 
   rh > 0, Q ∈ Reals, 
   Q >= 0, α ∈ Reals, α >= 0, 
   P ∈ Reals, P >= 0, L ∈ Reals, L > 0, 
   l ∈ Reals, l >= 0};
S[rh_, α_] = 
  3 α π^2 rh + 1/2 π^2 rh^3 // Simplify;
V[rh_] = (π^2 rh^4)/2 // Simplify;
ϕ[rh_, Q_] = (π Q)/(16 rh^2) // Simplify;
M[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] = 
  1/8 π (3 α + 3 rh^2 + 4 P π rh^4) + (
    8 rh^2 (ϕ[rh, Q])^2)/π // Simplify;
T[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] = (
   rh (π^2 (3 + 8 P π rh^2) - 64 (ϕ[rh, Q])^2))/(
   6 π^3 (2 α + rh^2)) // Simplify;
G[rh_, Q_, α_, P_] = 
  M[rh, Q, α, 
     P] - (T[rh, Q, α, P] S[rh, α]) - (ϕ[rh, 
       Q] Q) // Simplify;
f[r_, rh_, Q_, α_, P_] = 
  1 + r^2/(
     2 α) (1 - Sqrt[
       1 + (32 α M[rh, Q, α, P])/(
        3 π r^4) - (α Q^2)/(3 r^6) - (16 π α P)/
        3]) // Simplify;
Veff[r_] = f[r, rh, Q, α, P] (L^2/r^2 + 1) // FullSimplify;
eqn = L^2 == (r0^3* 
       D[f[r0, rh, Q, α, P], 
        r0])/(2 f[r0, rh, Q, α, P] - 
       r0 D[f[r0, rh, Q, α, P], r0]) // FullSimplify;

sol = Block[{α = 0.01, L = 20, P = 0.08}, 
  Solve[eqn, r0, Reals]]
```